# How to handle ConnectionError in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I have the problem that I get a `NameError` for the following code:

```
try:
    # some network programming raising an exception
except ConnectionError:
    # some error handling
```

This does not work, because you have to import `ConnectionError` from some module, which is not mentioned in the documentation (maybe I'm just blind?).
All I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054820/python-requests-exception-handling), but it refers to another request library.

Comment: It looks like you're using requests? It's docs are at http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

Comment: I am using http.client.HTTPConnection

Comment: What Python version are you using? From `http.client.HTTPConnection` it's obviously 3.x. But if you're getting a `NameError` on `ConnectionError`, it's not 3.2, 3.3, or 3.4.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I though the OSError reorg was in 3.2; it's actually 3.3. Let me edit my answer. But the short version is: You're _not_ getting a `ConnectionError`. Why do you think that's what you want to handle?

Comment: @mafrasi2: In other words, your problem isn't that you can't find `ConnectionError` in the 3.2 docs, but that you read some 3.3 docs, or some sample code written for 3.3, or something else that doesn't apply to 3.2, and it sent you on a wild goose chase.

Comment: jep, I wrote that code using python 3.3 on another machine and just didn't notice I have 3.2 on my notebook.

Comment: @mafrasi2: Well, I made the same mistake as you, as evidenced by my answer before editing it, so don't feel too bad. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the exceptions in the standard library that are expected to be "generally usable" are built-ins, and are documented in the [Built-in Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/exceptions.html#ConnectionError) part of the library reference.

In 3.3, that includes this one:

> *exception* `ConnectionError`
>
> A base class for connection-related issues.
>
> Subclasses are `BrokenPipeError`, `ConnectionAbortedError`, `ConnectionRefusedError` and `ConnectionResetError`.

But this is a built-in. So this should work:

```
except ConnectionError:
```

---

In 3.0-3.2, there *is* no such exception as `ConnectionError`. Nothing in the stdlib raises anything of that name. So there's no point in trying to handle it. (See [PEP 3151](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/) for an explanation of how `OSError` and `IOError` were reorganized between 3.2 and 3.3.)

The 3.2 equivalent of `ConnectionError` is `OSError` with certain `errno` values. So, what you want is something like:

```
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno not in (EPIPE, ESHUTDOWN, ECONNABORTED, ECONNREFUSED, ECONNRESET):
        raise
    # whatever you wanted to do for ConnectionError.
```

---

Meanwhile, in the future, when you don't know what kind of exception you need to handle, it's pretty easy to test. First, write some test code that handles *any* exception by logging the qualified name of the exception type. Then take the type out of the log and use that in your real code.

```
try:
    code_that_raises()
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e), type(e).__qualname__, whatever_else_looks_useful(e))
```

Comment: I am running python 3.2.3, but this does not work either. I cannot import the exceptions module and without import I get another NameError for exceptions :(

Comment: @mafrasi2: OK, updated; 3.2 is the same as 3.1, not the same as 3.3. There is no such error as `ConnectionError`.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe, this is true, but you are so right. I never got a ConnectionError, it was a socket.error

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  I'm using python 3.11, the code block you have worked without an import because `ConnectionError` is in a python built-in. However, the exception was not being caught.

It turns out `requests` 2.31.0 is using its own `ConnectionError` (!).  Once my except clause used `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError`, it worked for me.